# Iterate through all DBs - Get constraints in all tables

Tags: sql-server, foreach, constraints, sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to iterate through all databases by listing all table constraints.  I've achieved the following:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

SET @sql = 
'
USE ? 

select con.[name] as constraint_name,
    schema_name(t.schema_id) + ''.'' + t.[name]  as [table],
    col.[name] as column_name,
    con.[definition],
    case when con.is_disabled = 0 
        then ''Active'' 
        else ''Disabled''
        end as [status]
from sys.check_constraints con
    left outer join sys.objects t
        on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
    left outer join sys.all_columns col
        on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
        and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id
order by con.name
' 

PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @sql
```

I would like to have the query UNION all of my results in one clean select.

Can anyone help?

Using SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to insert the intermediate results into a temp table. Below is an example that also includes the database name in the results.

```
CREATE TABLE #results (
     [database_name] sysname
    ,[constraint_name]  nvarchar(128)
    ,[table]    nvarchar(257)
    ,[column_name]  nvarchar(128)
    ,[definition]   nvarchar(max)
    ,[status]   varchar(8)
);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

SET @sql = 
N'
USE [?];
INSERT INTO #results
select
    N''?'' as database_name,
    con.[name] as constraint_name,
    schema_name(t.schema_id) + ''.'' + t.[name]  as [table],
    col.[name] as column_name,
    con.[definition],
    case when con.is_disabled = 0 
        then ''Active'' 
        else ''Disabled''
        end as [status]
from sys.check_constraints con
    left outer join sys.objects t
        on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
    left outer join sys.all_columns col
        on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
        and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id;
'; 

PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @sql;
SELECT * FROM #results;
```